# grab a youtube playlist from a url

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I am using a function which fetches the video based on the video id. how to fetch a playlist from a url .
The function which I use to fetch the video based on id :

`var ytid = url.match("[\\?&]v=([^&#]*)");`

Comment: Did you check https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_playlists ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a playlist:
http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL1w1q3fL4pmhQXjaomvWqWf6QSnjtRn-3

This is also a playlist (at lease to me):
http://www.youtube.com/course?category=University%2FEngineering&feature=edu&list=EC6F144CF03CB2381B

The list id of both can be parsed by a little modification of your regex: 
`var listid = url.match("[\\?&]list=([^&#]*)");`